# How to make use of actionfiles between two packages?

Tags: catkin, ubuntu, actionlib, ubuntu-precise, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to make use of actionlib between two packages in the same workspace, but when I "catkin_make" the workspace I get the following error:

workspace/src/skills/src/master.cpp:63:33: fatal error: ur5_proxy/ur5Action.h: No such file or directory

The ur5Action.h plus additional action files are created in another package called ur5_proxy, and is placed in a directory called workspace/devel/include/ur5_proxy

So my question is how do I make use of actionfiles created in the ur5_proxy package in the skills package? I think the problem concerns the CMakelist or the package.xml.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128136/how-to-make-use-of-actionfiles-between-two-packages?/) by [mortenpj](https://answers.ros.org/users/7376/mortenpj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your target containing master.cpp needs to declare an explicit dependency on the messages:

```
add_dependencies(your_program ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

See the [catkin howto](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/building_msgs.html) for details.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0